# How to click a span in list without id with selenium webdriver python?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, xpath, webdriver

I can't click the "Span 1" through selenium web driver. this is inspect element from the web :

```
<div class="m-menu__subnav siak_menu_lm01" data-cek="02">
                    <ul class="m-menu__content">
                        <li class="m-menu__item">
                            <h3 class="m-menu__heading m-menu__toggle">
                                <i class="m-menu__link-bullet m-menu__link-bullet--line m--visible-tablet-and-mobile-table-cell">
                                    <span></span>
                                </i>
                                <span class="m-menu__link-text">AA</span>
                                <i class="m-menu__ver-arrow la la-angle-right"></i>
                            </h3>
                            <ul class="m-menu__inner">
                                <li class="m-menu__item" m-menu-link-redirect="1" aria-haspopup="true">
                                    <a href="dafduk/wni/dataKeluarga/searchList" class="m-menu__link ajaxify" data-cek="020101" data-target="siakContent" data-hidden="siakContentHandlebar" data-server="true" data-refresh="m_header_menu_default">
                                        <i class="m-menu__link-bullet m-menu__link-bullet--dot m--visible-tablet-and-mobile-table-cell">
                                            <span></span>
                                        </i>
                                        <span class="m-menu__link-text">Span 1</span>
                                    </a>
                                </li>
                                <li class="m-menu__item" m-menu-link-redirect="1" aria-haspopup="true">
                                    <a href="dafduk/wni/biodataEktp/searchList" class="m-menu__link ajaxify" data-cek="020102" data-target="siakContent" data-hidden="siakContentHandlebar" data-server="true" data-refresh="m_header_menu_default">
                                        <i class="m-menu__link-bullet m-menu__link-bullet--dot m--visible-tablet-and-mobile-table-cell">
                                            <span></span>
                                        </i>
                                        <span class="m-menu__link-text">Span 2</span>
                                    </a>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li class="m-menu__item">
                            <h3 class="m-menu__heading m-menu__toggle">
                                <i class="m-menu__link-bullet m-menu__link-bullet--line m--visible-tablet-and-mobile-table-cell">
                                    <span></span>
                                </i>
                                <span class="m-menu__link-text">BB</span>
                                <i class="m-menu__ver-arrow la la-angle-right"></i>
                            </h3>
                            <ul class="m-menu__inner">
                                <li class="m-menu__item" m-menu-link-redirect="1" aria-haspopup="true">
                                    <a href="dafduk/oa/dataKeluarga/searchList" class="m-menu__link ajaxify" data-cek="020201" data-target="siakContent" data-hidden="siakContentHandlebar" data-server="true" data-refresh="m_header_menu_default">
                                        <i class="m-menu__link-bullet m-menu__link-bullet--dot m--visible-tablet-and-mobile-table-cell">
                                            <span></span>
                                        </i>
                                        <span class="m-menu__link-text">Span 3</span>
                                    </a>
                                </li>
                                <li class="m-menu__item" m-menu-link-redirect="1" aria-haspopup="true">
                                    <a href="dafduk/oa/biodataEktp/searchList" class="m-menu__link ajaxify" data-cek="020202" data-target="siakContent" data-hidden="siakContentHandlebar" data-server="true" data-refresh="m_header_menu_default">
                                        <i class="m-menu__link-bullet m-menu__link-bullet--dot m--visible-tablet-and-mobile-table-cell">
                                            <span></span>
                                        </i>
                                        <span class="m-menu__link-text">Span 4</span>
                                    </a>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
```

I try to use this code :

```
clickSpan = driver.find_element("xpath",'//span[text()="Span 1"]')
clickSpan.click()
```

but that doesn't work, i get this error :

```
selenium.common.exceptions.ElementClickInterceptedException: Message: element click intercepted: Element <span class="m-menu__link-text">...</span> is not clickable at point (713, 175). Other element would receive the click: <div class="blockUI blockOverlay" style="z-index: 99999; border: none; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; width: 100%; height: 100%; top: 0px; left: 0px; background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0); opacity: 0.03; cursor: wait; position: absolute;"></div>
```

I am sorry, I am new to this selenium webdriver things. Can anyone help me? I really appreciate your help!

Comment: Your code can't click on a button which is hidden underneath another element, just like humans. You'll need to navigate the page to un-hide the button or simply delete the overlay first.

Comment: how do i navigate it?

Comment: WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//span[text()='Span 1']"))
).click()
try it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The below error message:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.ElementClickInterceptedException: Message: element click intercepted: Element <span class="m-menu__link-text">...</span> is not clickable at point
```

suggests that the desired element cannot be clicked as some other element is intercepting the click.

In such cases, you can try below ways to resolve it.

1. Use Selenium's [Explicit Wait](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/waits/):

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//span[text()='Span 1']"))).click()
```

Imports:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

2. Use [Actions Chains](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver/selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains.html):

```
time.sleep(5)
clickSpan = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//span[text()='Span 1']")
ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(clickSpan).click().perform()
```

Imports:

```
from selenium.webdriver import ActionChains
```

3. Use [`execute_script()`](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_remote/selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver.WebDriver.execute_script): **NOTE:** Use this option as a last resort. Using `Javascript` to perform `click()` operation is not an ideal way, as it won't imitate human actions.

```
time.sleep(5)
clickSpan = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//span[text()='Span 1']")
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", clickSpan)
```

Imports:

```
import time
```

Comment: it works! I am using the first way. Thankyou!